# Javascript check for 1 special character and 2 digits

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How to create a javascript validation for a password field which must contain at least one special character and at least two digits ?

Comment: use regEx `if (regEx.test(input)) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check(str){
    var temp = str;
    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false && temp.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length>1) return true;
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Exact regular expression that perfect match to your query is below, it is tested ...

```
^(?=.*?[0-9].*?[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{8,}$
```

Comment: I removed an extraneous `0-9` from the end of the square brackets